# Can I convert log-odds ratios to log-probabilities without numeric stability issues?

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods

I have a bunch of log-odds ratios $\ell$

$$\ell = \log\left(\frac{p}{1 - p}\right)$$

where $p$ is unknown. I want to get $p$

$$p = \text{logistic}(\ell) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\ell)},$$

but using this formula I have to evaluate $\exp(-\ell)$. When $\ell$ is very large in absolute value (and $p$ very small/very large), I might run into numerical stability issues on whatever platform I'm using. I'd ideally like $\log(p)$

$$
\log(p) = \log\left(\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\ell)} \right) = \log(1) - \log(1 + \exp(-\ell)) = -\log(1 + \exp(-\ell))
$$

but it seems like I can't avoid evaluating $\exp(-\ell)$! Is there any hack to obtain $\log(p)$ from $\ell$ without running into potential numerical stability issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerically, you'll have to deal with $\exp(-\ell)$ to some extent for a very simple reason: when $\ell$ is large, $\log p \approx -\exp(-\ell)$.

You definitely shouldn't compute $-\log(1 + \exp(-\ell))$, though: if $\ell$ is sufficiently large, $1 + \exp(-\ell)$ will just round off to $1$ and you get $\log p = 0$. But we have the inequality $\log (1 + x) \ge x(1-x)$ for $x>0$, and if $\ell$ is that large, then $1-x$ is $1$ to the degree that we can represent it at all: $x(1-x)$ and $x$ will have the same floating-point representations, and we can just set $\log p = - \exp(-\ell)$ with no trouble.

Of course, you need to worry about $-\log(1+\exp(-\ell))$ even when $\ell$ is large but not *that* large. You could deal with this case by using a Taylor series expansion, but this is a solved problem: most math libraries have a `log1p` command precisely for computing $\log(1+x)$ when $x$ is small.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `log1p`!

Comment: To clarify - when $\exp(-\ell)$, is very small, the numerical instability issue is not so much with $\exp(-\ell)$ as it is with $1 + \exp(-\ell)$, correct? Presumably this is because we can represent numbers $\approx 0$ much more precisely using IEEE 754 floating point numbers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006510/density-of-floating-point-number-magnitude-of-the-number/24179424#24179424)

Comment: That's exactly the issue. (And by the time we have trouble representing $\exp(-\ell)$, then we have the bigger problem that we can't represent $\log p$ very well, either.)

Answer (score 1):

You say $p$ is very small by which I assume you mean $p$ is much smaller than $1$.

As a first approximation, doesn't this suggest $1-p \approx 1$ so
$$\ell = \log{\frac{p}{1-p}} = \log{(p)}\, - \, \log{(1-p)} \approx \log(p)$$

Comment: Actually, when $\ell$ is very large, it's $1-p$ that's very small. (Of course, $\ell$ very large in absolute value and *negative* causes $p$ to be very small instead, and that's the other place where we run into numerical instability.)

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake with my question (which I've edited). In either extreme case of $\ell$ an approximation like the above does appear to hold. But I also need a general method even if $\ell$ is not that large in magnitude.

Comment: @jayelm no problem